# LaTeX symbol in moderncv

Tags: symbols

I want to get a nice looking LaTeX symbol while using `moderncv`. The regular command `\LaTeX` gives me this:

[image]

whilst I want this one:

[image]

Comment: `\LaTeX` just uses the current font so select a roman serif font rather than sans serif

Comment: That solves my problem. Thank you, sir

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This results from the default font setting under [`moderncv`](//ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) when using the `sans` document class option

```
\documentclass[...,sans,...]{moderncv}
```

You can either remove `sans` equivalent to forcing `roman`. However, if you want to keep the `sans` feel, locally force a `r`o`m`an font via

```
\textrm{\LaTeX}
```